# I deleted appcompat_v7 and now my Android projects won't work

Tags: android, eclipse

I noticed there were many projects in my workspace named appcompt_v7_x with "x" being 1,2,3,etc...

I looked at them and, not knowing they were used by my Android apps, I deleted them all. Well, now my Android projects won't compile.

Common erros are:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; (import cannot be resolved)
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; (import cannot be resolved)

R cannot be resolved to a variable

The constructor of TextView, Button and other subclasses of View are undefined
```

If I create a new Android project, it will create an appcompat_v7 project but it seems to only affects new projects, the older ones don't recognize the new appcompat_v7. If someone can help I would be really grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the appcompat_v7 project to your application project as a library:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
3. In the Library pane, click the Add button.
4. Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
5. In the properties window, click OK.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 0):

As,by default android apps gets saved in "workspace" folder .All you need is to delete that folder (make sure that you save your projects somewhere else) then run eclipse again and create a new empty project ,and your problem would be solved
as automatically appcompat_v7 folder gets created ,as you create new project

Seriously,it worked for me..